# How can I prevent unresponsive Core Data backed ScrollView?

Tags: swiftui, core-data

Here is my issue. I'm still new to SwiftUI, and this is on macOS.

I have a `ChatView` which should display a list of `ChatBubble`s. I'm using Core Data for everything that should be stored.

In ChatView, I initialize a FetchRequest as follows:

```swift
_messages = FetchRequest(entity: Message.entity(),
                         sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Message.date, ascending: false)],
                         predicate: NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", #keyPath(Message.belongs_to_convo), ce as CVarArg),
                         animation: .none)
```

where `messages` is declared as a `FetchedResults<Message>` with `@FetchRequest` property wrapper.

The last `ChatBubble` is displaying data that is streamed from a server, and the server writes its data directly into a `Message` (which is a Core Data managed entity). The problem I'm facing is that since there are many updates in quick succession, the UI becomes unresponsive (can't scroll) during the period of time when data is being added (which is usually about 10 seconds).

I couldn't quite pinpoint what specifically causes the stutter in Instruments, but after some playing around with `Self._printChanges()` on a `ChatBubble`, I found out that every time something is written in Core Data, all the `ChatBubble`s are re-drawn (even those that didn't change).

My two attempts at fixing this failed.

The first approach I took was to move writing to a background context (with `persistentStorage.newBackgroundContext()` and `backgroundContext.perform { }`). My hope was to free up some resources on the main thread, and it did, but the data is no longer reflected in real time on screen.

The second one was to split the FetchRequest in two: one for messages that don't change often (all except the last one), and one for the last message (which will udpate often).
I replaced the FetchRequest's predicate to `%K == %@ AND is_finished == true`, this fetches the expected messages but does not fix the issue, as every view is still redrawn as though there was an update to the `FetchedResults` whenever a message outside of the results is written to, even though there weren't.

I should add that a `ChatBubble` can be an expensive draw, as each one might contain advanced formatting and therefore might have a lot of processing to do.

Any idea ?

Comment: I would look into a solution that decouples the UI code from the server communication and persistence handling by creating a separate class (or more) for this and let it conform to ObservableObject and make use of async/await and have a @Published array with all the messages. Then the view could use this array property and it should also be easier to control how/when this property was updated.

Comment: You should post the view's code, or the view model's code: some variable there might be triggering the view update.

Answer (score 0):

@HunterLion's comment made me realise the mistake I made. While I wasn't updating the actual Core Data entity itself for each message, I was altering an other which they were all linked to via a Core Data relationship.